What does it mean when my cat's tail vibrates at the base
My cat often has the base of his tail vibrate (closest comparison would be the way you feel yourself vibrate when raising your arms over your head and stretching hard after a long period of sitting still). It typically happens when he's walking around my legs and his tail is standing up while still being relaxed (typical "calm, happy and affectionate" behavior).
Several of the cats I have owned over my life have had the same behavior, without ever having met each other. I feel like it's not a rare thing, though not all cats do it, yet there seems to be absolutely nothing written about it anywhere.
So, anyone knows what it's about?

does the shaking look like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovDBrgkVWpo ?

@trondhansen Very similar; in my case it's not quite as intense and only the lower half of the tail quivers (in the video something like 80-90% of the tail quivers)

That isn't rare. It is generally a signal that the cat particularly approves of something or some place, though it can be hard to be certain what.

Yeah, I was pretty confident it was an "I'm pleased" type of signal (since they do it only along with other happy social behavior) but I was curious if there was something specific about it that I might not know.

I can't offer any vaguely reliable guests about what it means to the cat. What does it mean when you chuckle?

@ keshlam
That's a good comparison. I could probably write an entire essay about what chuckling means in humans, just from personal experience, but it's wide enough and situational enough that there really isn't a better explanation than "chuckling is a sign of amusement in humans"

Guess, not guests, of course. GOTTA proofread better.
